# Preview Text Annotation Tool

Tags: preview, text

In a previous version of macOS the Preview app opened a box at the bottom of the screen and allowed me to click the A (type tool) and place the cursor where I wanted the text, then click to create a starting point.

The current version does not automatically create a text box when you selected the Text Annotation tool.

Can I change the way the current version of Preview works, to match this old behaviour? I don't like having to move the text box where I want it and highlight the word text to begin typing. It was so much easier and faster the old way.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different Barbara, I've substantially rewritten your question to improve the clarity of what you are asking, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree the new way of working isn't great, however the bad news is this is not configurable.

It's a core part of the operating system and the changes for better or worse are the way they are and it isn't a configuration setting sorry.

You could pass this feedback onto Apple here: https://feedback.apple.com